# Removing bath faucet fixture

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, faucet

I have an older bathroom sink fixture that needs some repair.  I was able to remove the allen screw and pull the handles.  But I can't remove anything after that.  I'm assuming the outer threads on the stem are the part that holds the bases on.  But I can't budge the bases by rotating.

Before I put a lot of force on it, is there any other thing I should be doing to remove them?

[image]

Comment: The part that holds them to the basin is usually a nut on the bottom side some times hard to get to with unless you have a faucet wrench that can reach up and unscrew the nut but many times can be done with needle nose pliers or a crescent wrench.

Comment: @EdBeal There is a single nut on the assembly under the basin.  But I assumed that held the whole thing and that I could instead remove the decorative base from the stem separately.

Comment: The decorative base should rotate and screw off the external thread of the the stem assembly. The large contact area of the decorative base against the basin skirt means there could be a lot of force required if the break it loose - especially if any scale built up under the decorative base flange.

Comment: Although it is unclear why the right unit does not have the same metal part on top of itself like the left one does. Also there is some beady looking stuff on the left one that may be some kind of sealer or glue placed there for unknown reasons.

Comment: @MichaelKaras, that's it.  Please make it an answer.  Difficult to see at the resolution, but the unit on the right simply has some dark scale on top.  there is no metal top on either one. I finally got a pipe wrench out and was able to get sufficient torque to turn it.  It didn't feel to be stuck to the basin, just tight on the stem.